# which system command should i use to get the desired output given below

Tags: command-line, system, ps, uptime

I need to write a system program that imitates `who` and `w`.Print the time since login(in the form HH:MM:SS)and the host name. Allow for a command line option `-p` that also prints the interesting processes that the user is running.nicely intended on the lines beneath the main user line.
eg.

```
23:45:11 vkbhardwaj-Inspiron-5558
11009 -tcsh
13032 vi a.c
13033 ps axl
```

i have  used this command

```
alias vk="awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime;hostname;pgrep -l"
```

but it's throwing error for this command as:

```
awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing '(')
3600):int((%3600)
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near :
vkbhardwaj-Inspiron-5558
pgrep: no matching criteria specified
Try `pgrep --help' for more information.
```

please help ASAP

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell function instead of an `alias` is simplier I think.

Something close to what you want would be:

```
vk() { lastlog -u "${USER}" | awk -v ORS="" 'END{$1="";$2="";$3="";print}' ; hostname ; if [[ $# > 0 && $1 == "-p" ]] ; then ps -u; fi;}
```

The date and time of last login is printed instead of `the time since login`